# AWS CTAS: How to double quote values?

Tags: amazon-athena

In AWS Athena, how can I specify having the values double quoted `"value"`. I managed to specify the delimiter using the `field_delimiter` expression.

Comment: do you want double quote on all the fields including numeric, date data types etc? Or selectively on string data only? Also how many columns in the table?

Comment: Yes on every column. The number of columns is not important.

Comment: I have posted my suggestion as answer below for better formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have table cust_transaction with two columns id, amount where amount is int datatype, you can CTAS is as follows. The approach is quite manual and can be cumbersome if the number of columns are big. You will need to explicitly cast non-string data types to varchar too. Hope that helps. Is it what you were looking for?

```
create table cust_transaction_pipe_1
with (external_location = 's3://aws_bucket/cust_tx_pipe_1/',format='TEXTFILE',field_delimiter = '|')
as 
select concat(chr(34), id ,chr(34)) as id,concat(chr(34) , cast(amount as varchar) ,chr(34)) as amount from cust_transaction
```